# Put some code with minted in an a0poster

Tags: listings, minted, a0poster

I am using Overleaf to create my poster with the class `a0poster`.
I have a question about introducing a code (SPARQL) in a `minted` block for a poster.

When I used a `minted` block, with `beamer` or `article` class, it works fine.

However, when I want to use it into a `minipage`, I have an error due to extra `}`. However, I have no extra `}`.

Is it possible to used `minted` or `listing` with `a0poster` class?

My last thing will be to put a screenshot of my code, but I think it would be easier to directly write my code into my LaTeX code.

```latex
\put(0.18074571,0.56315264){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{
     \begin{minipage}{0.15928631\unitlength}\raggedrigh
     \begin{minted}[baselinestretch=1.2,fontsize=\scriptsize,linenos]{sparql}
        PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>%
        PREFIX ask: <http://ask.org/data/> 
        SELECT ?G ?S1 ?S2 {
        GRAPH <graph> {
            {SELECT DISTINCT ?G1 ?S1 ?S2 
            WHERE {
             ...
            }}

           }}
    \end{minted}
    \end{minipage}}}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem is not the `minipage`, it's the `\put` command: verbatim environments, such as `minted` do not work inside the argument to other commands.

Comment: Ohh ! so I have no choice but to take a screenshot of my code and include it as a graphic.. thank you for your answer !